# Rotation of parallel lines

Tags: r, rotation

Consider these two parallel segments in a plot.

```
plot(c(1, 6), c(2, 2), type="n", xlim=c(0, 7), ylim=c(-2, 6))
segments(1, 1, 6, 1)
segments(1, 3, 6, 3)
```

How can I rotate the two lines together by a defined angle?

Thank you all in advance.

Best,
Antonio

---

Here some observations after the answer.

If we use the function that returns the degrees of a segment in a Cartesian space to the segment used in the example:

```
segments(1, 1, 6, 1)
angle <- function(x, y) return( atan2((y[2]-y[1]), (x[2]-x[1]))*(180/pi) )
```

Then we get zero degrees, because it is an horizontal line.

```
angle(c(1, 6), c(1, 1))
[1] 0
```

However, by applying the function provided:

```
> xyrot<-function(pairs,ang){
>     # pairs must be Nx2 matrix w/ x in first column and y in second
>     xrot <- pairs[,1]*cos(ang) - pairs[,2]*sin(ang)
>     yrot <- pairs[,1]*sin(ang) + pairs[,2]*cos(ang)
>     return(invisible(cbind(xrot,yrot))) }
```

to rotate 90 degrees the segment example...

```
rot90 <- xyrot(matrix(data=c(1, 1, 6, 1), nrow=2, ncol=2, byrow=TRUE), 90)
```

...then the angle returned is higher than 90 degrees.

```
angle(as.vector(c(rot90[1,1],rot90[2,1])), as.vector(c(rot90[1,2],rot90[2,2])))
[1] 116.6202
```

And the plot does not show a vertical line either.

```
plot(rot90)
segments(rot90[1,1], rot90[1,2], rot90[2,1], rot90[2,2])
```

Am I missing something?

---

Sí, `ang` should be as radians :)

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is very useful to get the coordinates through the rotation matrix. Now I need to get the lines...

Comment: Well, once you have the coordinates, presumably paired up, e.g. first line is `rotatedpairs[1:2,]` , second line is `rotatedpairs[3:4,]` , it should be pretty easy to write a loop to plot all the lines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this:

```
# coordinate transform: cartesian plane rotation
xyrot<-function(pairs,ang){
    # pairs must be Nx2 matrix w/ x in first column and y in second
    xrot <- pairs[,1]*cos(ang) - pairs[,2]*sin(ang)
    yrot <- pairs[,1]*sin(ang) + pairs[,2]*cos(ang)
    return(invisible(cbind(xrot,yrot)))
}
```